# Average not calculating right in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a work in progress code. As you can tell, I am a complete beginner and been trying new things. I usually get an error and I try and fix that but here this one is not giving me any error. It's just that the answer to the average is a wrong number. Without any error, its hard for me to know what's wrong with the code. Any suggestion?

```
sum = 0.0
count = 0
ids = [ ]
scores = [ ]

ids = eval(input("Enter an id number:"))
if ids <= 0.0:
  print("Can't be 0 or a negative number, please enter a number    greater than 0")
  exit(1)
scores = eval(input("Enter a score:"))
while ids >= 0.0:
  ids = eval(input("Enter another id number (or 0 to quit):"))
  if ids <= 0.0:
    break
  scores = eval(input("Enter another score:"))
  sum = sum + scores
  count = count + 1

avg = sum / count

for i in range(ids):
  print(i)
print("The average of the scores is", avg)
```

Comment: `ids = int(input('your text'))`

Comment: Side-note: Naming a variable `sum` means you cut off access to the `sum` built-in function. Best to avoid doing so.

Comment: How are you inputting your inputs?

Comment: Is this using python 2.x? It's the only thing I can think of that would result in a "wrong" answer. Also please give your input, your output and your expected output.

Comment: I am using python3

Comment: It looks like you're discarding the first score, without including it in `sum`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a few examples: ie. if I give it 3,4,5, I expect 4, but get 91

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in your code.

First of all in python you must use right indentation.
Next you have declared `ids = [ ]` and `scores = [ ]` without any reason
Why do you use ids?
Instead of `eval(input())`, use `int(input())`

A simple code to calculate average:

```
scores = list(map(int, input('Enter Space Separated Elements : ').split()))
print('Average is ' + str(sum(scores) / len(scores)))
```

Explanation:

1. Learn about `input` [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/input)
2. Learn about `input().split()` [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/split)
3. Learn about `map()` [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/map)
4. As `map` returns a map object, we must convert it to a [list](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list)
5. Learn about `sum`, `len` and other built-in functions [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this but I have started back up from the beginning and the average seems to work out fine now.